# Set maximum length in Text field in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Has anyone managed to set maximum field lenghts for text fields

How can i set the maximum length of a text field.
Here is the code iam using

```
<%= text_field_tag(:create_text), :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40}  %>
```

but I cannot seem to set the max number of characters that can be typed into
the field.

Comment: Why do you use the input_html hash? You should pass the parameters directly, you are not using Simple form (f.input).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'create_text', nil, :maxlength => 15, :size => 40 %>
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

Answer (score 20):

In the **text_field_tag** call:

**:size** relates to the physical length of the text box. It will be big enough to allow that many characters to be visible in the box. But the user can still enter more.

**:maxlength** is the maximum number of characters the user can enter, regardless of the physical size of the text box. The text box can be bigger or smaller, but if you set :maxlength => 5, they will only be able to enter 5 characters.

If this is a hard limit you want for the data in the database, too, you should set a validation. This prevents you from, for example, setting it to more characters in your Rails code.

```
validates_length_of :column_name, :maximum => 5
```

Finally, for a belts and suspenders approach and to prevent even code that goes against the database from setting a bad value, you can enforce it at the database level. In some cases, other code than your Rails app might update the database. This prevents bad data even in this case.

Adding a column in a migration you do it like this:

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, :limit => 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Client Side:

```
      <%= text_field_tag :"description", '', maxlength: 5   %>
   or      
     <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" maxlength="5">
```

Server Side: That is inside the model.rb file

```
validates_length_of :column_name, :maximum => 5
```

Answer (score -5):

you can try this

```
<%=text_field_tag 'create_text',:size=>40 %>
```